# Migrate auto generated IDs from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration, liquibase, conceptual

I am currently developing a java application to migrate data of an Oracle database to an equivalent structured SQL Server database which I have migrated using liquibase. Now I could not figure out how to migrate the auto generated IDs as well since it is something which is not accessible so easy. I want them to have the exactly same values as in my source database and I want them to be ongoing so when the last auto generated ID was 177 für example I want the next generated on to be 178. I know that this is a vague question but currently I am just thinking about a concept to apply in my code so any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can try to use "SET IDENTITY_INSERT <tablename> ON" before insert the data! After this you could change. Check "DBCC CHECKIDENT " to change start value of the identity column after insert.

Comment: SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle will do all this for you.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54258

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This should be definitely posted as an answer. Btw. does SSMA handle [GENERATED ALWAYS](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) columns and/or custom increment automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept is to move data from Oracle to SQL Server as-is using SSIS/linked server/Polybase/bcp:

```
INSERT INTO SQL_Server_table(id, ...)
SELECT id, ...
FROM Oracle_table;
```

If table has `IDENTITY` property then you have to disable it first:

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT SQL_Server_table ON`

Once you have data moved you need to set identity to highest value:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('SQL_Server_table', RESEED, <max_calculated_value>+1);
```

---

If the table does not have identity column defined you could use `SEQUENCE`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.SQL_Server_table_seq
START WITH <max_calculated_value>+1
INCREMENT BY 1 ;  

ALTER TABLE SQL_Server_table
ADD CONSTRAINT df_SQL_Server_table_seq 
DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SQL_Server_table_seq FOR [<identity_column>];
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5d41ede08073ca0138099ee215508b7b)**

Comment: why do I need to set identity to highest value?

Comment: @MadScientist To avoid clash once you want to insert new data. Check the provided example